# How to get keys of CSV file as a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to store the keys of the following CSV file as a list:

```
"first_name","last_name","email","mobile"
"rahul","sivadas","rahul@gmail.com",783434513
"mary","tomy","mary@gmail.com",9839383894
"vijay","govind","vijay@gmail.com",9283747393
"vikas","raj","vikas@gmail.com",239848392
"ajay","r","ajay@gmail.com",982934793
```

how to get its keys as a list:

```
['first_name','last_name','email','mobile']
```

I have tried:

```
>>> with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
        header = csv.header(f)
        print header



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in <module>
    header = csv.header(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'header'
```

Comment: That was because my question was downvoted, Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) certainly doesn't have a `header` attribute, as the error traceback tells you. I think you probably wanted a [`csv.DictReader`'s](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) `fieldnames` attribute:

> The *fieldnames* parameter is a *sequence* whose elements are associated with the fields of the input data in order. If the *fieldnames* parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the *csvfile* will be used as the fieldnames.

In use:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    print reader.fieldnames


['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile']
```